# jQuery show and enter div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

There are answers to the question how to show a div when hovering over another div, but in my example I need to hover over an anchor tag which shows a list of menu bar items and after that to go with the mouse over that list of menu bar items. After that, when I mouseout the entered list, the list should hide. The problem is when I hover out of the menu bar list, it does not disappear.

I tried to do it when hovering over `js-expand` to show `js-am-content` and when `mouseout` over `menu-bar-item` to hide the content if `menu-bar-item` is not hovered on, but the content does not hide.

This is my simplified HTML

```
<div>
  <a class="expand js-expand fa fa-bars"></a>
  <div class="action-menu-content js-am-content">
    <a class="menu-bar-item"> SHOW </a>
    <a class="menu-bar-item"> EDIT </a>
    <a class="menu-bar-item"> COLLECTIVE </a>
    <a class="menu-bar-item"> PER ORDER </a>
    <a class="menu-bar-item"> CUSTOMS </a>
    <a class="menu-bar-item"> HISTORY </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and jQuery (coffee script)

```
$(document).on 'mouseover', '.js-expand', (event) =>
  $parent = $(event.currentTarget).parent()
  $parent.children(".js-am-content").slideToggle('fast')

$(document).on 'mouseout', '.menu-bar-item', (event) =>
  if !$('.menu-bar-item:hover') 
    $('.js-am-content').fadeOut('fast')
```

Comment: Can you add your entire html so that the use case can be prepared in jsfiddle OR Can you please provide jsfiddle for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try this :

```
 $(document).on 'mouseout', '.menu-bar-item', (event) =>
    $('.js-am-content').fadeOut('fast');
```

I mean why do we need to check for "item:hover" when we are already making mouseout  event on the parent

Comment: I tried that, but when I go over with the mouse to the next menu item the whole list disappears. I made a video with that code that you wrote and here it's how it looks: https://youtu.be/K0At-lW3ccQ

Comment: The Video is unavailable my friend

Comment: Sorry, it was private. Now it's available.

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible to add the event handler to the parent `<div>` then try this.

```
$(".parentdiv").hover(
    function(event) {
      $(event.currentTarget).children(".js-am-content").fadeIn("fast");
    }, function(event) {
      $(event.currentTarget).children(".js-am-content").fadeOut("fast");
    }
  );
```

If u can't add the handler to the parent let me know and I'll try something else.

PS: Sorry that this isn't coffee script.